# Turn json object value become a key and value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have a json format as below. I am very confused, can we make the first value as the key and the second value as the contents of the key?

```
[
  {
      "configSlug": "receiptStoreName",
      "configContent": "The Store Name"
  },
  {
      "configSlug": "receiptStoreAddress",
      "configContent": "Cattle Street"
  },
  {
      "configSlug": "receiptStorePhone",
      "configContent": "01 123234"
  },
  {
      "configSlug": "receiptStoreFoot1",
      "configContent": "Thanks For Visiting"
  }
]
```

Expected Result:

```
{
    "receiptStoreName": "The Store Name",
    "receiptStoreAddress": "Cattle Street",
    "receiptStorePhone": "01 123234",
    "receiptStoreFoot1": "Thanks For Visiting"      
}
```

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Please post the code you have written yourself in an attempt to solve the issue so that we can help you debug it. Remember that SO is here to help you solve issues in your code, not to write code for you. If you need help approaching this issue, research the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

Comment: For help. Look to using reduce method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const obj = [
  {
      "configSlug": "receiptStoreName",
      "configContent": "The Store Name"
  },
  {
      "configSlug": "receiptStoreAddress",
      "configContent": "Cattle Street"
  },
  {
      "configSlug": "receiptStorePhone",
      "configContent": "01 123234"
  },
  {
      "configSlug": "receiptStoreFoot1",
      "configContent": "Thanks For Visiting"
  }
];

const result = Object.fromEntries(obj.map(entry => [entry.configSlug, entry.configContent]));

console.log(result);
```

Or you can use a simple loop:

```js
const obj = [
  {
      "configSlug": "receiptStoreName",
      "configContent": "The Store Name"
  },
  {
      "configSlug": "receiptStoreAddress",
      "configContent": "Cattle Street"
  },
  {
      "configSlug": "receiptStorePhone",
      "configContent": "01 123234"
  },
  {
      "configSlug": "receiptStoreFoot1",
      "configContent": "Thanks For Visiting"
  }
];

const result = {};
for (const entry of obj) {
  result[entry.configSlug] = entry.configContent;
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), like this:

```js
const data = [
  {
      "configSlug": "receiptStoreName",
      "configContent": "The Store Name"
  },
  {
      "configSlug": "receiptStoreAddress",
      "configContent": "Cattle Street"
  },
  {
      "configSlug": "receiptStorePhone",
      "configContent": "01 123234"
  },
  {
      "configSlug": "receiptStoreFoot1",
      "configContent": "Thanks For Visiting"
  }
];
    
const result = data.reduce((r, e) => {
  r[e.configSlug] = e.configContent;
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Which gives the output:

```
{
  receiptStoreName: "The Store Name",
  receiptStoreAddress: "Cattle Street",
  receiptStorePhone: "01 123234",
  receiptStoreFoot1: "Thanks For Visiting"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data.reduce((obj, item) => { obj[item.configSlug] = item.configContent; return obj; }, {});
```